# How to use addEventListener for this?

Tags: javascript, oop, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener to child divs within a container div. I am having an issue with figuring out how to do this properly. The code I have so far is here: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7Nc2hwZ6). The listener (click) is on line 35

Comment: Lisenter ? I imagine you mean Listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `context` function instead of passing it as a listener. I mean, this:

```
divs[i].addEventLisenter('click', context(divs[i].id), true);
```

should be:

```
divs[i].addEventLisenter('click', context, true);
```

And this:

```
function context(id) {
    console.log(id+' clicked');
}
```

should be:

```
function context(evt) {
    console.log(this.id + ' clicked');
}
```

Comment: Ah, interesting... though I found a different way to do what I want. (i.e. add the click event to the container div, and get the event.target.id of the child divs.

Comment: @Charles, What you're doing is very useful! If you dynamically add new children to the container, the click listener will work for them too (unlike with the traditional method above). It's known as "event delegation".

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is interpreted, so you should move the definition of docINIT above the use of it.

Comment: Not necessarily true -- interpreted has nothing to do with it. Look into JavaScript variable hoisting. The function can exist and be defined any where in the scope.

Comment: tkone is correct, I have been using that layout method for docINIT in several applications, never had an issue.